# Creating Swagger JSON Schema File out of Dataverse Web API

Tags: json, integration, dataverse, swagger

We have an integration project happening where a microservice would be connecting to Dataverse Web API through a middleware. I know direct point to point integration is possible but this is organization policy to establish integration through middleware only. The middleware team has demanded for a Swagger file created out of Dataverse Web API. What are the ways/tools to generate this Swagger JSON schema. I have already tried postman tool but it creates empty responseBody when exported as postman collection which would be invalid for Swagger file creation. Also tried SwaggerHub Explorer but that too not working as it is not returning any output.